# Ionic cordova build android stuck at splashscreen

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

so I have my app working without errors on web and now I want build android apk file and test it, so I do :

```
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova build android
```

I get no erros after these two.

Then I go to the android studio and run android project, build succefull. 
After I launch my app, i see ionic splashscreen only spinning for 1 second and after that he stops, thats it. Stuck at splashscreen.

ionic info :

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.1 (C:\Users\Andrejus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   NodeJS : v8.11.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Plugin list :

```
com.unarin.cordova.beacon 3.7.0 "Proximity Beacon Plugin"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 2.3.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-ionic 4.2.0 "IonicCordova"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```

In android studio I always get this error :

```
09-11 15:41:11.427 6218-6277/com.port4you.app D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost:8080/assets/icon/favicon.ico
09-11 15:41:11.435 6218-6218/com.port4you.app D/CordovaWebViewImpl: onPageFinished(http://localhost:8080/)
09-11 15:41:11.459 6218-6218/com.port4you.app D/SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost:8080/build/polyfills.js: Line 3 : Unhandled Promise rejection:
09-11 15:41:11.459 6218-6218/com.port4you.app I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Unhandled Promise rejection:", source: http://localhost:8080/build/polyfills.js (3)
09-11 15:41:11.485 1938-2864/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-11 15:41:11.485 1938-2864/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
09-11 15:41:15.188 1938-1956/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-11 15:41:15.188 1938-1956/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
09-11 15:41:15.201 1938-1956/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-11 15:41:15.201 1938-1956/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
```

This error every 4-5 seconds :

```
09-11 15:41:15.201 1938-1956/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-11 15:41:15.201 1938-1956/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
```

RUN ERRORS :

```
D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost:8080/assets/icon/favicon.ico
D/SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost:8080/build/polyfills.js: Line 3 : Unhandled Promise rejection:
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Unhandled Promise rejection:", source: http://localhost:8080/build/polyfills.js (3)
W/com.unarin.beacon: WARNING did not receive delegate ready callback from DOM after 30 seconds!
D/SystemWebChromeClient: : Line 1 : WARNING did not receive delegate ready callback from DOM after 30 seconds!
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "WARNING did not receive delegate ready callback from DOM after 30 seconds!", source:  (1)
D/CordovaActivity: Paused the activity.
W/com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger: deactivateApp events are being logged automatically. There's no need to call deactivateApp, this is safe to remove.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7566c1c5dba0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x7566d142bde0)
D/CordovaActivity: Stopped the activity.
D/CordovaActivity: CordovaActivity.onDestroy()
W/BeaconManager: This device does not support bluetooth LE.
                 Method invocation will be ignored.
Application terminated.
```

console.error :

[image]

Comment: I think one of your plugins may be having problems and making splash screen all wonky. Try to delete some like the Facebook one and trying again if that fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Open Chrome and go to chrome://inspect/#devices

Then inspect your remote device and check console tab. You're probably facing issues with plugins.

You can also run with

```
ionic cordova run android -c
```

This way you can check console on your command.

Comment: can I inspect devices if running on emulator ? Dont have android.

Comment: ionic cordova run android -c doesnt work either without android.

Comment: You can inspect emulators with Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: I am using android studio, when i write that url u wrote, i get nothing - url not found

Comment: added console error, but it doesnt really says to me anything , can u check ?

Comment: Are you using any bluetooth method? There's a line in your erro log saying your device does not support Bluetooth.

Comment: Fixed that by disabling plugin ibeacon