# Ionic transfer project to blank project

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

got some problems with android build - it's not working after build. Now I want to try transfer all my ionic 4 project to blank ionic 4 project. Is there anyway of doing it properly ? Because I know that I need to install cordova and it's plugins manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove and re-add Android

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

And you need to give more information about your problem (console errors)

Comment: here is the link of my android build problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279677/ionic-cordova-build-android-stuck-at-splashscreen

Comment: after these lines my app dont work : 

D/SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost:8080/build/polyfills.js: Line 3 : Unhandled Promise rejection:
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Unhandled Promise rejection:", source: http://localhost:8080/build/polyfills.js (3)

Answer (score 0):

1. just pass all the pages in `src/pages` to the new
2. add them to your new `app.modules.ts` in `src/app`
3. and finally pass your `package.json` replacing for the blank projects one

> the package.json contains all plug-ins that you installed

- after replacing all files just run 
  `$ npm install` in the blank project's page 
  all your plug-ins will be properly installed again

**if even after this ionic doesn't recognize the plug-ins**

- just run `ionic state restore --plugins`

> for more info :
>   https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/install-or-reinstall-all-cordova-plugins-in-package-json-with-ionic